# mediarecorder.requestdata returns nothing

Tags: javascript, chromebook, mediarecorder-api

I am using the MediaRecorder APIs in my Chromebook extension application.

The problem is that the size of the data returned by `mediarecorder.requestdata` is zero. The capture stream is fine and `mediaRecorder.ondataavailable` is called, but the data size is zero always.

This is my configuration:

```
var mimeType = 'video/webm;codecs=h264,pcm'; 
var bitsPerSecond; 
var options = { 
  mimeType: mimeType, 
  ignoreMuteMedia:true, 
  video:{ 
    maxWidth:1280, 
    maxHeight:720 
  } 
}; 
haveAudio = false; 
sampleRate = 48000; 
frmcnt = 0; 
//if (quality === 'low') { options.bitsPerSecond = 4000000; } 
var mRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
```

Comment: I will help you by editing your question with the comments to my answer. After the update my answer makes no sense, so I deleted.

Comment: You'll need to show when you call `requestData`. From what you've given, the recorder is never started, (so requestData should throw). Alos note that `requestData` is a void method, it will only force a dataavailable event but won't return anything.

Comment: thanks but the " mediarecorder.start()" has be called and the "mediarecorder.onstart" is be called      this  is  my  code  "         mediaRecorder.start();
          settimeSlice=setTimeout(function fnn(){
        mediaRecorder.requestData();
            setTimeout(fnn,67);
       },67);"

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue here.
Try this:

```
mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', function(e) {
console.log(e.data);
});
```